read email messages from sub-folder in one request
I want to retrieve a list of messages for user support@company.com from a sub/child folder of Inbox called Customer emails.  What is the correct URL? I've tried various like
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('support@company.com')mailFolders/inbox/childFolders/Support%20emails/messages
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('support@company.com')/mailFolder('Inbox/Support%20emails')/messages
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('support@company.com')/mailFolders/inbox/childFolders('Support%20emails')/messages
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('support@company.com')/mailFolders('Inbox/Support emails')/messages

without success, although
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('support@company.com')/mailFolders/inbox/messages
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('support@company.com')/mailFolders('Inbox')/messages

successfully retrieve the messages in the Inbox folder.  I feel sure that it is possible to use some notation like mailFolder('Inbox/Support%20emails') to avoid having to obtain the sub-folder id. as an intermediate operation, which would involve having to obtain the Mail.ReadBasic permission which I currently lack.

Only well-known folder names are supported as an alternative to folder id.
Still, you can list child folders of the Inbox, expand messages and filter child folders by displayName.
GET /v1.0/users/support@company.com/mailFolders/inbox/childFolders?$expand=messages&$filter=displayName eq 'Customer emails'

If you need only some subset of message properties, use $select inside the $expand.
GET /v1.0/users/support@company.com/mailFolders/inbox/childFolders?$expand=messages($select=id,subject)&$filter=displayName eq 'Customer emails'

$top inside the $expand is also supported.
GET /v1.0/users/support@company.com/mailFolders/inbox/childFolders?$expand=messages($select=id,subject;$top=999)&$filter=displayName eq 'Customer emails'

Be aware that if Customer emails has more 999 messages, expand will probably contain only 999 messages.
